# How to discuss the continuity of a function?

Tags: limits, continuity

How to discuss the continuity of this function because it doesn't give a range in the first & third part. 
The function is $F\colon [0,1] \to \mathbf R$ with
$$F(x)= \begin{cases} \cos x, \quad & x=0 \\ \frac{x \ln x}{x-1}, & 0<x<1 \\ -1, &x=1. \end{cases}$$

Comment: What is your function?

Comment: F(x), it should be cosx when x = 0, it should be (x/1-x)ln x when 0<x<1, & it should be -1 when x = 1

Comment: Okay, here we go. So the function is $F\colon [0,1] \to \mathbf R$ with
$$F(x)= \begin{cases}
\cos x, \quad & x=0 \\
\frac{x \ln x}{x-1}, & 0<x<1 \\
-1, &x=1
\end{cases} $$?

Comment: It's not clear. It shows me something like a programming code

Comment: Maybe refresh the site. I dont know. Have a look at my answer please. This might help.

Comment: @NiklasHebestreit can you give it as a separate answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume we are analyzing the function $F\colon [0,1] \to \mathbf R$ with
$$F(x)= \begin{cases} \cos x, \quad & x=0 \\ \frac{x \ln x}{x-1}, & 0<x<1 \\ -1, &x=1. \end{cases}$$

**Hint:**

To check where $F$ is continuous you **only** have to check the critical points $0$ and $1$. Therefore you have to check if
$$F(0)=\cos 0 =1 \stackrel{?}{=} \lim_{x\to 0+ \\ 0<x<1} \frac{x \ln x}{x-1} = \lim_{x\to 0+ \\ 0<x<1} F(x)$$
and
$$F(1)=-1 \stackrel{?}{=} \lim_{x\to 1- \\ 0<x<1} \frac{x \ln x}{x-1} =\lim_{x\to 1- \\ 0<x<1}  F(x).$$

Comment: I don't know how to calculate the value of f(x) when 0<x<1

Comment: There is nothing to calculate. The value is given.

Comment: Where....? I don't understand

Comment: Can I please know that this is continuous or not?

Comment: Which part of my answer dont you understand and why? I really want to help you!

Comment: 0<x<1 range. & Why have you put "?" on equation mark

Comment: Please read my answer **carefully** and think about it.

Comment: But still I can't understand

Comment: I got the answer... yes... it is continuous in that range